# Generate a Facebook share box for my app

Tags: facebook

Is there an easy way to generate the Facebook share box for my own app (see image below for what I mean)?

Users of my app will be able to share many of the same things that the this current box allows and wondered if the Facebook api can just generate it or do I would have to style the whole thing from scratch?

[image]

Comment: as far as i know, no fb api for that, you got to design your own thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing available for you to use is: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/  But that doesn't have all the cool options of Status/Photo/Link/Video/Question/Security.  You will have to build your own form to collect that information and then HTTP post it to the appropriate graph object.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was afraid I'd have to style the whole thing...nightmare!